# Using PHP POST variables when adding data to mySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I want to take the POST data from the three form tags and upload variables to mySQL. When I run the PHP on the second page I get a "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'VALUES' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPtest\signUpTRUE.php on line 32**"

I can try to post the HTML Form Tags and the PHP..

The HTML form tags:

```
<div id="headingText"><p> New Fan Club Registration</p></div>

            <form action="signUpTRUE.php" method="post" >
                <div id="firstNameField">First Name:<input type="text" name="fname"></br></div>
                <div id="lastNameField">Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"></br></div>
                <div id="emailField">Email: <input type="text" name="email"></br></div>


                <div id="checkboxField"><input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="agree" id="checkboxField" required> *Agree to the <a href="newText.php" id="termsLink">terms and conditions</a> </input></div>

                <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">Submit</button>

            </form>
```

Here is the PHP running calls to mySQL:

```
<?php


        $FN = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']);
        $LN = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']);
        $EM = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "password";
        $dbname = "fanClub";

        $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

            if ($conn->connect_error)  {
                die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

            }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO userInfo (email, firstname, lastname)"
        VALUES ($EM, $FN, $LN);


        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "<p> data enrty has been logged like whoa</p>";
        }else {
            echo"<p>error in code.</p>";
        }

        $conn-close();


    ?>
```

I get the

"**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'VALUES' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPtest\signUpTRUE.php on line 32**"

when I try to run this.

Thanks a lot for looking at this :D!

Comment: you've missed your double quotes in line 32

Comment: There is nothing to do with mysql or POST or something. `Parse error: syntax error` is mean it is just syntax error in your PHP source file. In this case you forget to quote and concatenate `VALUES ($EM, $FN, $LN)` string and just wrote it as php code. But this is NOT php code. :)

Comment: Ok. I am honestly learning what PHP code is. I still ran this code with the corrections posted on the page and nothing is being saved to mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userInfo (email, firstname, lastname)"
        VALUES ($EM, $FN, $LN);
```

This line is wrong. It should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userInfo (email, firstname, lastname) VALUES ($EM, $FN, $LN)";
```

Anyways your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: I'm writing this script to save data right now. After this I get this down I'll focus more on preventing SQL injection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're seeing that specific error is because on line 32, you're incorrectly calling the close method of your conn class:

```
$conn-close();
```

This is missing the closing angle bracket, and should be:

```
$conn->close();
```

After you fix this error, you will then most likely see an error for the incorrect SQL formatting as pointed out in the other answers. This will most likely be a function not defined error, as you probably don't have a function called VALUE($a, $b, $c) somewhere.

Comment: Thank you. I've been staring into this laptop for a while now. I don't know how I missed this. I made a more practical error. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I took care of the misplaced double quote and the > symbol but the data isn't saving to mySQL still the if else statement returns an "error in code" and I checked mySQL and no data is present?

Comment: It wouldn't be possible to diagnose the issue with just the code you've posted thus far, even with the corrections listed in place. I would assume your $conn->query($sql) call is preparing and executing the statement, but one can't really attempt to problem solve something from an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userInfo (email, firstname, lastname)"
VALUES ($EM, $FN, $LN);
```

should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userInfo (email, firstname, lastname)
    VALUES ($EM, $FN, $LN)";
```

(Note where the closing quote is.)

Actually, it should be

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO userInfo (email, firstname, lastname)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

and then you can use it as a [prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $EM, $FN, $LN);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The displayed error can be corrected as follows:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userInfo (email, firstname, lastname) VALUES ($EM, $FN, $LN)";
```

Also please correct the last line as follows:

```
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues in query

- extra double quotes between columns and values.
- not using single quotes between string values.

**Modified query**:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userInfo (email, firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$EM', '$FN', '$LN')";
```

**Side note**:

Also check the `close` function as mentioned in other answer correct your typo error.